# I don't understand the meaning of the following sentence

Tags: meaning

Can anyone explain the meaning of the following sentence.

She will be getting all poshed up for a banquet.

I would like someone to explain or paraphrase it in other words.

Thanks

Comment: She will be taking a great deal of trouble over her appearance because she is going to a banquet.

Comment: **What** in the sentence do you not understand? *Poshed up* actually has a [dictionary entry](https://www.lexico.com/definition/poshed-up).

Answer (score 0):

It means:

> she will smarten (decorate / tidy up) everything for a banquet (formal meal).

Somehow it means that she will prepare all things and everybody in an up-to-date and luxurious way for the event.